# How to simplify "for loop" and "boolean variable" statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a section of code looks like this

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "orange", "apple"]

found_apple = False

for f in fruits:
    if f == "apple":
        found_apple = True
if not found_apple:
    raise ValueError('Apple is not found')
```

I can feel a bad smell
so I simplify it to like:

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "orange", "apple"]

if not any([f for f in fruits if f == "apple"]):
    raise ValueError('Apple is not found')
```

but it increase the space complexity because it create a list.
How can you simplify it and make it more redable without losing the time complexity and space complexity?

Comment: `if 'apple' not in fruits:..raise ..`

Comment: Likely a duplicate for the link @Maroun shared

Comment: If you are looking for a way to improve your code and not fix it then I think you might want to head over to [codereview.se], as this question seems more like a performance or best practice and design question

Comment: oh ok thank you i didn't know there is a code review forum.